# How to select one of records on one field SQLite Android randomly

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've SQLite database table like this :

```
_id  ||   Column1   ||    Column2    ||
1    ||    test1    ||   a,b,c,d,e,f ||
2    ||    test2    ||   g,h,i,j,k,l ||
3    ||    test3    ||   m,n,o,p,q,r ||
```

How do I select one random of Column2 from this table?

I want the result like this :

```
_id  ||   Column1   ||    Column2    ||
1    ||    test1    ||   d           ||
2    ||    test2    ||   k           ||
3    ||    test3    ||   r           ||
```

assumed that d, k, r is random value of Column2 for each records.

Thanks

UPDATES :
I've create CustomAdapter and add some View like this :

```
  @Override
  public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
      Cursor c = getCursor();
      final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      View v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
      int column2Name= c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COLUMN2);
      String col2Name= c.getString(column2Name);
      String[] temp;
      Random random = new Random();
          temp = col2Name.split(",");
          String col2 = temp[random.nextInt(temp.length)];
      TextView col2_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.column2_label);
      if (col2_name != null) {
          col2_name .setText(col2);
      }
      return v;
  }

  @Override
  public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
      int column2Name= c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COLUMN2);
          String col2Name= c.getString(column2Name);
          String[] temp;
          Random random = new Random();
              temp = col2Name.split(",");
              String col2 = temp[random.nextInt(temp.length)];
          TextView col2_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.column2_label);
      if (col2_name != null) {
          col2_name .setText(col2);
      }
    }
```

Now, just use that customAdapter on your activity, so that column2 can be show as 1 random value.

Comment: try `SELECT column FROM table order by random() LIMIT 1;`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253561/sqlite-order-by-rand

Comment: no, i mean, not all columns show randomly, but just records on Column2

Comment: yup yup or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114940/select-random-rows-in-sqlite

Comment: i don't want to all rows select randomly, just Column2 value, select 1 randomly

Comment: as i said `SELECT Column2 FROM table order by random() LIMIT 1;` look at the first example :))

Comment: if you want to select one of the comma separated values of the Column2  you cannot do it with sqlite alone. have to implement it in any programming language you know.

Comment: >.< i want to show _id, Column1, Column2 like the result above, man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be much easier to do in Java once you have the data from the DB.

```
Random RANDOM = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

int index = cursor.getColumnIndex("Column2");
String value = cursor.getString(index);
String[] values = value.split(",");
String randomValue = values[RANDOM.nextInt(values.length)];
```