# Display random values From Sqlite Database Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova, random

I'm using Cordova Database and I have to display my images in the database randomly. Sqlite order by Random() is not working ...
Here is my code

```
Var myDB = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo",10485760);
myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {

    transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM YOUTUBE_VIDEOO ORDER BY RANDOM LIMIT 6 ', [], function(tx, res){
        for(var iii = 0; iii < res.rows.length; iii++)
        {
            $('#uTubeLst').append("<div style='float:left;padding:10px;'><img src ='data:image/png;base64,"+res.rows.item(iii).imgSRc+"' width=40 height=50  ></div>");
        }

        function(transaction){

            var $lastNo = "";
        }
    }, null);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use braces because `RANDOM()` is a function, so your query string would look something like

```
'SELECT * FROM YOUTUBE_VIDEO ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 6'
```

**UPDATE**

This seems to have a really poor performance, look at this thread for informations and alternatives: [Select random row(s) in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114940/select-random-rows-in-sqlite)