# Is there any function in Android to output random stuff from a collection of things in database ? For more details read information given below

Tags: java, android, android-application-class

I am making an Android app for automatic generation of question paper. In which I've made a database where I've stored questions but I'm facing problem in generating ramdon questions so that questions don't get repeated in the same question paper. Is there any specific function to generate random question from question set?

Comment: For more details read information given below - what you mean.

Comment: I am making an Android app for automatic generation of question paper. In which I've made a database where I've stored questions but I'm facing problem in generating ramdon questions so that questions don't get repeated in the same question paper. Is there any specific function to generate random question from question set?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Random keyword for order by and `limit` the number of record you want.

```
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " + limit, null);
   // use the cursor data
```

If you have data in List use below link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4229001/8603832

Comment: For a better performance see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114940/select-random-rows-in-sqlite

Comment: Thank you so much . I'll surely try this.