# How to select a random row in DbFlow?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, dbflow

How to get a random row from a table in DBFlow?

In SQLite I would simply write the query as:

`select * from table_name ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;`

Whats the equivalent for it? I couldn't find anything and OrderBy accepts only column values. Thank you.

My question is about DBFlow ORM for Android, not for SQLite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select random row(s) in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114940/select-random-rows-in-sqlite)

Comment: That's for SQLite, I asked the question for DBFlow.