# How to jump to the next part on Android test application?

Tags: android

I'm working on a test application. I coded that for now and it's working good for first question. But I don't know how to go second question. I tried to use while-do loop and something else for to do that but didn't work. What can I do? Can anyone help me for that?

```
public class testing extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testing);

        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.soru1);
        final Button answer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        final Button answer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        final Button answer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        final Button answer4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);

        final ArrayList<String> questions= new ArrayList<String>();
        countries.add("question1");
        countries.add("question2");
        countries.add("question3");
        countries.add("question4");
        countries.add("question5");
        countries.add("question6");
        countries.add("question7");
        countries.add("question8");

        final int[] answers= new int[]{
                R.drawable.pic1, 
                R.drawable.pic2,
                R.drawable.pic3,
                R.drawable.pic4,
                R.drawable.pic5,
                R.drawable.pic6,
                R.drawable.pic7,
                R.drawable.pic8,
                R.drawable.correct,
                R.drawable.wrong,

                };

        Random soru = new Random();
        final int[] rastgele = new int[1];
        for (int i=0; i<1; i++)
                {rastgele[i]= soru.nextInt(8);}

         ArrayList<Integer> cevap = new ArrayList<Integer>();          
         for (int k = 0; k <= 7; ++k) 
            {cevap.add(k);}
         Collections.shuffle(cevap);

         final Integer[] rastgele2 = new Integer[4];
                    if (rastgele[0]!=cevap.get(0))
                    {rastgele2[0]=cevap.get(0);}
                    else
                    {rastgele2[0]=cevap.get(3);}
                    if (rastgele[0]!=cevap.get(1))
                    {rastgele2[1]=cevap.get(1);} 
                    else
                    {rastgele2[1]=cevap.get(3);}
                    if (rastgele[0]!=cevap.get(2))
                    {rastgele2[2]=cevap.get(2);} 
                    else
                    {rastgele2[2]=cevap.get(3);}                    
                    rastgele2[3]=rastgele[0];
                    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(rastgele2));  

        view.setText(questions.get(rastgele[0]));
        answer1.setBackgroundResource(answers[rastgele2[0]]);
        answer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            if (rastgele[0]==rastgele2[0])
                {answer1.setBackgroundResource(answers[8]);
                questions.remove(rastgele[0]);}
            else {answer1.setBackgroundResource(answers[9]);}
                                        }
        });
        answer2.setBackgroundResource(answers[rastgele2[1]]); 
        answer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            if (rastgele2[1]==rastgele[0])
            {answer2.setBackgroundResource(answers[8]);
                countries.remove(rastgele[0]);}
            else {answer2.setBackgroundResource(answers[9]);}
                                        }
        });
        answer3.setBackgroundResource(answer[rastgele2[2]]);   
        answer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (rastgele2[2]==rastgele[0])
            {answer3.setBackgroundResource(answer[8]);
                countries.remove(rastgele[0]);}
            else {answer3.setBackgroundResource(answer[9]);}
                                        }
        });
        answer4.setBackgroundResource(answer[rastgele2[3]]);
        answer4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (rastgele2[3]==rastgele[0])
            {answer4.setBackgroundResource(answer[8]);
                countries.remove(rastgele[0]);}
            else {answer4.setBackgroundResource(answer[9]);}
    }
        });}
}
```

Comment: `What can I do?` with what? `Can anyone help me for that?` with what? for FSM sake where is the question? what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

to move to a new activity, see this post [How to open a second activity on click of button in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194081/how-to-open-a-second-activity-on-click-of-button-in-android-app)

In your existing layout you need this

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:onClick="RandomButtonNameHere"
    android:text="@string/button" />
```

Then in your existing JAVA you want to launch a new activity intent onclick

```
public void RandomButtonNameHere(View view) 
{
Intent intent = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

where `FromActivity` is the name of your current java file and `ToActivity` is the name of your new java file, ignoring the .java extensions

I.e. Question1.Java to Question2.Java would be

```
public void ButtonToQuestion2(View view) 
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Question1.this, Question2.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

and called by the button in your Question1.xml

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:onClick="ButtonToQuestion2"
    android:text="@string/ButtonToQuestion2" />
```

Note that the name of my button is defined in my strings list but you could rename `"@string/ButtonToQuestion2"` to `"Name of Button"` for a static name

Comment: But I want to generate random lots of questions. So I cant use new activity for all of those. All must be in aactivity.

Comment: ahh right, sorry about that, I didn't realise / see that you wanted random questions... Could you load the questions from a database? if stored in your SQLite DB on the phone? This would also easily enable you to update the questions at a later date, without having to change the whole app...

Comment: Check out this post for details on SQLite Random Selecting...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279706/select-random-row-from-an-sqlite-table

Answer (score 0):

Given that you use the same view to indicate correctness of the answer, you need some additional trigger - I'd suggest to add "next" button to your layout.

Then, factor out piece of code that sets views for a question (selecting country and resources for the answers) into a method `void setUpQuestion(int questionIndex)` that takes question number as an input. Create memver vaiable `int currentQuestion = 0` for using as an input to `setUpQuestion()`

In `OnClick()` method for "next" button increment `currentQuestion` and call `setUpQuestion()` to update views.