# Get random record in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, random

I fetch records in my SQLite database like this.

```
spellId = extra.getString("spellId");
DBase db = new DBase(this);
db.open();
String[] data = db.getRecord(Integer.parseInt(spellId));
db.close();
```

Can I get random data like this without using raw queries and cursor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select random row from an sqlite table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279706/select-random-row-from-an-sqlite-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Random#nextInt()` like

```
String[] data = db.getRecord(new Random().nextInt(num));
```

where `num` falls in the range of your record IDs. You would need to adapt this solution in case your Ids are fragmented and do not form a consecutive range.

One of the ways to do that would be to first create a query to fetch all the primary keys and store the values in a set somewhere. Then pick a random key by generating an index using `Random`.

```
String[] data = db.getRecord(IDSet.get(new Random().nextInt(IDSet.size())));
```

Check out the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) for more information.

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value **between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)**, drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

---

#### If you're considering a DB query solution

A better alternative to using `ORDER BY RANDOM()` (which is known to not scale well as the number of rows in your table grows) is to let SQLite return a random row using an `OFFSET`.

First save the total number of rows `num` somewhere.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM spells;
```

Then choose a random number `rnum` between `(0, num)` using `Random` and use the query

```
SELECT * FROM spells LIMIT 1 OFFSET rnum;
```

Comment: But the number of records in my database isn't constant. Is there an equivalent for the getCount() of cursor in this way of accessing the db?

Comment: Is `spellId` the primary key of the table or does it work like an index in a list of fetched db records?

Comment: It is. I fetch it using a Bundle from the previous activity.

Comment: I've just added a DB query solution as well.

Answer (score 13):

try like this:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mainTable ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);
```

Comment: This would work but is not recommended for large tables. `Order By Random()` doesn't scale well with the number of rows.