# SQLite: ...EXCEPT ... ORDER BY RANDOM()

Tags: sqlite, random, sql-order-by, sql-except

This query:

```
SELECT colour FROM ColourView
EXCEPT SELECT colour FROM SkinColourExceptionsView
WHERE race = 'Human' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

Produces the following exception:

```
1st ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set
```

However, changing `ORDER BY RANDOM()` to `ORDER BY colour` is able to produce results (sorted alphabetically by colour rather than randomly).

The following suggests that `ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1` should work: [Select random row from a sqlite table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279706/select-random-row-from-an-sqlite-table).

Can someone explain why my query doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound), the ORDER BY term(s) must match some column in the result set.

You can work around this restriction by moving the compound query into a subquery:

```
SELECT colour
FROM (SELECT colour FROM ColourView
      EXCEPT
      SELECT colour FROM SkinColourExceptionsView WHERE race = 'Human')
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 1;
```

Alternatively, rewrite the query to use a different filter mechanism:

```
SELECT colour
FROM ColourView
WHERE colour NOT IN (SELECT colour
                     FROM SkinColourExceptionsView
                     WHERE race = 'Human')
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 1;
```