# How to select random row not by id SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I`m maked SQLite database like

```
      ID  |  CHAPTER  |  Content
  --------------------
   1  |  1    |  xxxxxxxxx
   1  |  2    |  xxxxxxxxx
   1  |  3    |  xxxxxxxxx
   2  |  1    |  xxxxxxxxx
   2  |  2    |  xxxxxxxxx
```

how to get random row content from database?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Select random row from an sqlite table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279706/select-random-row-from-an-sqlite-table)

Have a look at [Selecting a Random Row from an SQLite Table](http://www.bernzilla.com/2008/05/13/selecting-a-random-row-from-an-sqlite-table/)

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```